# VBA pasting array date values in different format

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a simple macro that includes a dynamic array which fills up upon conditions are met. The data populates the macro as it is supposed to be functioning until it paste the data onto the spreadsheet. Now, all data is pasted correctly except for date values. Date values are pasted erroneously from European format to American format onto the spreadsheet (i.e. dd-mm-yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy). So for instance a 1st march 2019  becomes a 3rd January 2019 on the spreadsheet. Note that either I format beforehand the destination files or not, the problem still occurs.

The array has 14 columns and only column 12-13 are date values.

**Edit Summary**

Shredded the code from irrelevant information; added images of results.

**Following is the code**

```
Sub Verification()
    Dim NewWorkbook As String, NewWorksheet As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
    Dim LoopCounter As Long
    Dim NewEntryCounter As Long
    Dim Cols As Long, Rows As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim arr As Variant, NewEntry() As Variant
    Dim myRange As Integer

    NewWorkbook = LCase(InputBox("What is the name of the new report?"))
    NewWorksheet = LCase(InputBox("What is the name of the sheet?"))
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wb.Sheets("Renouvellement")

        Cols = Workbooks(NewWorkbook).Sheets(NewWorksheet).Range(Workbooks(NewWorkbook).Sheets(NewWorksheet).Cells(1, 1), Workbooks(NewWorkbook).Sheets(NewWorksheet).Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)).Count
        Rows = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Count

        For Each r In Workbooks(NewWorkbook).Sheets(NewWorksheet).Range("A2", Workbooks(NewWorkbook).Sheets(NewWorksheet).Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        If (r.Offset(0, 21).Text = "Red" Or r.Offset(0, 21).Text = "Blue") And r.Offset(0, 17).Value >= 24 Then
            arr = Application.VLookup(r.Value, sh.Range("A:A"), 1, 0)

            If IsError(arr) Then
                NewEntryCounter = NewEntryCounter + 1
                ReDim Preserve NewEntry(1 To Cols, 1 To NewEntryCounter)
                For LoopCounter = 1 To Cols
                    NewEntry(LoopCounter, NewEntryCounter) = r.Offset(0, LoopCounter - 1)
                Next LoopCounter
            Else

End Sub
```

**Sample results from Local window**

[image]

**Sample results when transferring date values onto spreadsheet**

[image]

As you can see the first value inserted is changed when transferring data from vba to spreadsheet. The second value is correctly transferred. The third is not, and so on.

Comment: What is the format of the destination column to which the dates are being pasted?  What are your Windows Regional Settings short date format (I suspect `DMY` or similar for that).

Comment: The dates that do *not* change would not be valid dates if reversed (there's no 13th month, for example, on that second data point). That explains why some dates change. As mentioned in other comments, how the data is displayed is a function of the formatting applied to the cells. This has nothing to do with the code - the information is being carried over correctly. After the macro runs, select this column then go to Format/Format Cells. Look in the "Number" tab and you'll probably see that the "Locale" is not what you think it should be. Change the locale and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: @CindyMeister I think you got it right. The values get messed up once pasted on the spreadsheet. I checked and the days above the 13ths are stored as general format

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I cannot access to Windows Regional Settings as I do not have permission

Comment: Update: If I insert on an Excel cell a random date such as 01/07/2018 I encounter the error "Ambiguous name detected: Verification date"

Comment: Did you read my entire comment, about trying to format the "backwards" dates in the Excel UI to test whether that's a possible approach to solving the issue?

Comment: There are things going on in the background that are playing a role in your problem.  That error message is not a standard Excel error, so may be being triggered by data validation or an event-triggered macro. But if you don't know the format of the destination column to which the data is being pasted, and you cannot access the hidden information, all I can suggest is to try to move the data in a different manner.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have tried to format dates backwards, and it does not work. I have tried chancing the locale in different European formats before and after the macro runs but no luck either.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I do not have data-validation nor event triggering macro, but I agree with you that something is off place. Now, I can change the format of the destination column, and I can access hidden information (I do not have administrative powers at windows level tho). How do you suggest me to proceed? Because I have never modify arrays' content after I compiled them.

Comment: 1. My previous question:  What is the format of the column in Excel to which your numbers are being pasted? (before the pasting).  2. What happens if you try a different method of copying -- eg the answer I provided?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld here are my findings. 1. Pasting the array to destination cells formatted with general or date format returned me the same problem (note I did it before pasting). 2. Cutting entire rows or copying date cells (in the traditional way, as you have proposed) resolves the problem. Finally, I would rather stick with array method: first because filters do not apply in my case and second to learn how to prevent the error from happening in the future- even though your traditional pasting would be more viable to finish up the job quickly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `filters do not apply`.  It seems from your code that you are filtering the data based on looking for `red`, `blue` and `>24` in certain columns.  But perhaps you can avoid your array problem by converting the values to `Double` before pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Again, it's a bit difficult for me to understand exactly what you're doing, but it seems that a filter might be simpler, so far as the copying of relevant data is concerned.

In your code, you are making multiple calls to the worksheet, and multiple `Redim Preserve` operations on the VBA array.  Those operations can be costly.

Perhaps that part of the code could be simplified (and sped up) with something like (obviously, you may need to change the worksheet and range variables):

```
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set r = ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
With r
    .AutoFilter field:=22, Criteria1:="red", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="blue"
    .AutoFilter field:=18, Criteria1:=">=24"
End With

r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'Paste somewhere

ws.ShowAllData
```